# how to convert https to http using java script in html page

Tags: javascript, html

how to change https to http using java script in html page ?

I have Done some code to change https to http but does not work in my html page

can you please help me . I want to Know how to change https to http using java script in html page

Comment: how to convert https to http using java script in html page ?

Comment: What do you mean by "convert" we can't help you if you don't even know the basics

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do, post some code to show what you have tried, and explain what happens and what you expect.

Comment: i have a project in ftp .while i run , it  open in https . how will i disable. I want to open it in http.

Comment: If you're trying to redirect your website to use https instead of http or visa-versa its always better to do it server-side. So either php or in a .htaccess configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try first, but let me give some snippet code to give idea.

You need to use [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

**I am giving you about two cases**, this is just to make understanding.

If you want to **convert the current url**, then you should use "window.location.href" to take current url,

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace(/^https:/, 'http:');
```

And when you want to **convert of any specific url** then

```
var custom_url = "put your url here"
window.location = custom_url.replace(/^https:/, 'http:');
```